# A Zinc (4.x) application can't be opened from CD, but can open from desktop in Mac

Tags: macos, flash, cd, mdm-zinc, zinc-4

I compiled a faily simple application that just loads images, text and opens some pdfs via mdm.System

It works exactly as intended on Windows, but on Mac, it doesn't even try to launch when it's on the disc, but when copied to anywhere it will. The swf used its under Flash Player 8, because it uses AS2. Moreover, the "bundled" version of the flash player used on Zinc is 10. The mac tested was an OSX 10.6.8.

Finally, to give context, the icon of the app on the cd displays as default (the engine thingy) but when copied out of the CD it turns back to my custom one...which is weird.

Is it some kind of restriction from the system? or is the data corrupted in some way?

I think it could be solved if there was a way to "append" the mdm plugins into a regularly created mac projector (e.g. just with Adobe Flash)

thank you for reading.

Comment: If you make a standalone mac projector just using pure Flash and put it on a CD does it do the same thing?

Comment: Are there any console messages?